# Populate a temp table with a listing of numbers to a maximum from data

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I want to populate a list of row numbers into a temp table to the maximum number from another table. For example, I want to add 1,2,3,4,5 etc. up to a the max 45.

The other table where the max is coming from misses out some row numbers (ie 1,3,5,11) which is why I can't use that table.

My poor attempt so far is the following, but this only gives me the max number and not a sequential number listing. There is probably some inbuilt table/function I've forgotten about.

```
DECLARE @reportTable TABLE (row int, [1] nvarchar(max), [2] nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @reportTable (row, [1], [2])
SELECT MAX(row), '', ''
FROM @Days
```

Your assistance is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Brain switched on finally...

```
DECLARE @rowmax as int
DECLARE @rowcount as int
SET @rowmax = (SELECT MAX(row) FROM @Days)
SET @rowcount = 1

WHILE @rowcount<=@rowmax
BEGIN 
    INSERT @reportTable(row) 
        SELECT @rowcount; 
    SET @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
END
```